# CSS :focus selector doesn't work when element is focused with .focus()

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, focus

I'm attempting to highlight focused `<tr>`s.

I've added a tabindex of `-1` to each of them, and confirmed that  calling `some_tr.focus()` sets `document.activeElement` to that `some_tr`. However, for some reason `some_tr` isn't then highlighted by the `tr:focus` CSS rule.

It should be noted that, for me (Firefox 54), clicking a `<tr>` manually *does* cause it to be highlighted.

```js
document.getElementById("that_tr").focus();
console.log(document.activeElement);
```

```css
tr:focus {
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>part</th>
    <th>peice</th>
    <th>thing</th>
    <th>stuff</th>
  </tr>
  <tr tabindex="-1">
    <td><span>data1</span></td>
    <td><span>data1</span></td>
    <td><span>data1</span></td>
    <td><span>data1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="that_tr" tabindex="-1">
    <td><span>data2</span></td>
    <td><span>data2</span></td>
    <td><span>data2</span></td>
    <td><span>data2</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Why doesn't `that_tr` become highlighted in the above snippet? How can I get this to work?

Comment: I see the highlighting when I run your snippet.

Comment: It works in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: I can confirm it's not working in Firefox 54.0a2

Comment: @Barmar The last tr is highlighted light blue as soon as "run code snippet" is clicked?

Comment: @IiroP So is this a browser bug then..?

Comment: Yes, it's highlighted as soon as Run Code Snippet is clicked. If I then click somewhere else the highlighting goes away. I just tried it in FF 53.0.2.

Comment: @Barmar Hm. Doesn't do that for me even with FF 53.0 (though I haven't tested 53.0.2)

Comment: Could it be OS-related? I'm on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: @Barmar That seems to be it. I can reproduce the instant highlight on OS X Yosemite, but not on Archlinux or Windows Vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but I've found that my code works for me (Firefox on linux) when run from an event listener. This seems to be a quirk of the browser, and possibly a bug.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  document.getElementById("that_tr").focus();
  console.log(document.activeElement);
});
```

```css
tr:focus {
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>part</th>
    <th>peice</th>
    <th>thing</th>
    <th>stuff</th>
  </tr>
  <tr tabindex="-1">
    <td><span>data1</span></td>
    <td><span>data1</span></td>
    <td><span>data1</span></td>
    <td><span>data1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="that_tr" tabindex="-1">
    <td><span>data2</span></td>
    <td><span>data2</span></td>
    <td><span>data2</span></td>
    <td><span>data2</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is good enough for me, as I intended to run this inside an event listener anyway. That said, I wouldn't mind learning the reason for this behavior (if any).